# How do I get a reference to the "InnerMessages" of an Exception in

Tags: c#, exception

In my application, a System.Exception is thrown that has information I would like to report on.  When debugging, there is an item under the Exception called "InnerMessages".  It is an array of the actual errors that occurred.  However, I cannot find a way to access InnerMessages to add the data to my log.

How can I reference this?  Here is a print screen showing what I am trying to reference:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the result of `ex.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: It's a property, not a method, so you shouldn't be calling it with parentheses. Apart from that, I am presuming that you're using something like `catch (Exception ex)`, and `ex` is the base `System.Exception` type instead of a more specific exception that is being thrown.

Comment: The fullname is "PX.Data.PXOuterException".  vgru, you are correct that it is a base exception.  It is being thrown by the application I am customizing (Acumatica).  I found an example online where someone showed e.InnerMessages() so I thought I'd try it.  It doesn't compile with or without the parens.  If it is a property, it seems like I should be able to grab it.   Thanks for replying and helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Guru Stron, you helped me figure this out with your suggestion.

Sorry for the dumb question.  My lack of c# skills is to blame.  The exception type was not a System.Exception.  That is why there were properties not part of the System.Exception.

The exception was a custom Acumatica exception.